# SP2010: Edit Top Navigation Bar Subsites - Duplicates

Tags: 2010, navigation, top-link-bar

I have a top bar with some headings, one of which is `Research Center`. When I hover over `Research Center` there are a handful of links to sites. How do I edit whichlinks show up?

Primarily, there are two links with the same title, `Career Pathway`, that link to the same subsite.

I have tried using `Site Actions > Site Settings > Navigation`. When I do that from `Research Center` it only allows me to modify the left bar. When I do this from the home page, it lists `Research Center` as `URL: /research center` with an icon that looks like a site tree diagram with one subsite as red and does not show the subsites of `Research Center`

[image]

Second Picture:

[image]

Third Picture:

[image]

Comment: Hi, if you add screenshot of Navigation Setting that will be helpful.

Comment: @PS Sorry I missed this - just uploaded a screen shot.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a sub site, you have an option to use the top link bar from parent site. If you select that option, you can modify the top navigation only from the parent site's `Site Settings -> Navigation` (which I believe is your case). This might be the reason you are not seeing the top navigation links in `Research Center` site.
So try going to the top level site and then go to

`Site Settings -> Navigation`. Here you should be able to modify the top/global navigation links.

Comment: Thanks for the info. However, I can see the top navigation links. The problem is that when I hover of one, I see too many subsites (there is a duplicate of one). Any thoughts on how to remove the duplicate?

Comment: Are you able to see the top navigation links when you go to                    Site Settings -> Navigation page ?

Comment: Yes - but I do not see the subsites under `Research Center`in the Navigation page, just `Research Center` and then the other top navigation links that are at the same level.

Comment: Are you using managed navigation(term store) or structural navigation for global navigation? This can be seen in navigation settings.

Comment: how do i tell? My navigation settings say `Title: Global Navigation` `URL: `  `Description: `  `Type: Container`. I couldn't find info on this with google (except for SP 2013).

Comment: Oh, I am sorry. You said SharePoint 2010. Never mind.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35193/discussion-between-shashank-reddy-karam-and-as3adtintin).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it might be inheriting the Global Navigation from the parent site.

Navigate to the parent site, and look at it's **Navigation** settings: `[URL]/_layouts/AreaNavigationSettings.aspx`

The **Show Subsites** option may be enabled. Try disabling that to see if it removes duplicates. What I have found is that sometimes people try manually link to a sub-site, then later on someone enables this checkbox and you end up with duplicates.

[image]

Deleted incorrect edit

Comment: thanks for the suggestions. However, I do want to show all the navigation items on the top bar, and not just the ones below the current site.

Comment: What exactly are hoping to display? If you uncheck that check box, you will be free to edit the Global Navigation area as you please. If you share a screenshot of the Navigation page we should be able to get it resolved rather quickly.

Comment: I updated with a picture. In the dropdown "Career Pathways" is listed twice and is the same site. (note: "Career Path" is a separate site)

Comment: From the screenshot, the Navigation settings are only displaying the left hand side navigation items. You can see that what is rendered on the left hand side of the page ("Research Center", "Research Reports", "Non-faculty Staffing") is available for edit in the "Navigation Editing and Sorting" section.

You will also notice that "Display the same navigation items as parent site" is selected. This means that the top level bar navigation is powered from the parent site. Navigate up to the parent site, and you will be able to edit the navigation items there, and remove/hide the duplicate.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I added a second screen shot of the navigation section from the home (parent) page. I think I understand what you are talking about, however I do not see the subsites off of "Research Center" - and thus do not know how to edit them.

Comment: I understand your issue now. Can you share the entire screenshot of the navigation page? I'd be curious to see what the settings are on the sections above the navigation editing panel.

Comment: for sure! I updated the second picture

Comment: I've tried to reproduce this in my own environment. What I am seeing is that the dropdown is being populated from the pages I have in my site. If you visit the "Research Center" site, do you have two Pages in a library, one called "Career Path" and another called "Career Pathways"?

Comment: I do - so I believe if I delete "Career Path" site the link will go away. However, I only have one "Career Pathways" site yet two links in the dropdown. I am not sure if this happened when renaming the site or how...

Comment: And they differently point to the same site? Click on site-settings and "View all site content" scroll down to the sub-sites and ensure that "Career Pathways" isn't in there twice.

Comment: Under Research Center "View all site content" and "Sites and workplaces", there is only one Career Path and one Career Pathways. I can take a screenshot if that would help you

Comment: Perhaps I could delete the sites and then remake them? Do you know of an easy way to do that so I do not have to remake the site by hand? I'm thinking of just copying the site right now... (Unless you think you can address the original duplicate question - which might allow us to sleep better at night ;) )

Comment: I would be weary of deleting and recreating the sites as I believe this should be solvable through the UI, however if you're adamant and the site contains content, I would save it as a template (google saving SharePoint site as template) and recreate the site using the template. It will create with all the content in it. Firstly, I would try editing the Navigation settings in parent site, and unselect "Show Subsites" under the Global Navigation settings, and saving that. Then go back in and select it again, and see if that makes any difference.

Comment: Well if you think it should be solvable through the user interface i'm happy to continue looking for the solution with you - but thank you for the copy info should it come to that

Comment: The "Show subsite" uncheck and check is tempting, however I am worried about affecting other dropdowns. For example - in Directory and Meetings there are three sublinks but only two subsites (in picture 3 above). Do you think there is a chance "COFHE calendar" will be removed? I do not know how I would put it back

Comment: I don't think it will affect it, but don't do anything you are not comfortable with. It will be hard to debug this through here it appears. My advice would be to play with the navigations settings a bit. I'm still convinced that it is being pulled from a sub-site or a page within the Research Center site.

Comment: right it does seem strange. the navigation pulls strictly from "sites and workspaces", yes? can it pull from anything else?

Comment: I have had it pull and display pages from the Pages library.

Comment: how did you do that?

Comment: There is a "Show Pages" as well as a "Show Subsites" option in the navigation settings. Have a play around with it all and you'll quickly see how it's all pulled together.